# When are objects destroyed?

Tags: c++, oop, class, object

I'm wanting to confirm the behaviour that will happen in the following situation. Suppose I have some functions defined as:

```
std::vector<Object*> FuncA()
Result FuncB()
```

Where result is a class with constructor

```
Result(const std::vector<Object*>& result)
{
    this->result = result;
}
```

Now, FuncB does the following:

```
Result FuncB() {
 ... some stuff here ...
return Result(FuncA())
}
```

When will the vector returned by FuncA be destroyed (have its destructor called)? Will it be when Result goes out of scope? Does result holding a reference to it extend its lifetime? If not could you please explain why and maybe a way to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks

Edit: Here's the result class

```
class Result
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Object*> result;

        void SetData(const Result& other);
        void Free();

        // Constructs the result and takes ownership of the memory.
        Result(const std::vector<Object*>& result);

        Result();

    public:
        Result(const Result& other);
        Result& operator=(const Result& rhs);
        ~Result();

        const Object& operator [] (int index);
    };
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `Result`. The answer depends on what is stored inside.

Comment: Don't use a vector of pointers, it's going to be very easy to create memory leaks. If you don't want `std::vector<Object>`, at least use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Result` holds a reference, then you have a problem. The object returned by `FuncA` will be destroyed before the `Result` object is returned.

Now, `Result` holds by value. This means that the return value of `FuncA` will be copied in the constructor. The vector will be destroyed when the `Result` object is.

If you want to avoid the copy, [take the object by value in the constructor](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/):

```
Result(std::vector<Object*> result) 
    : result(std::move(result))
{}
```

or, if you don't use C++11 (cf @Steve Jessop's comment)

```
Result(std::vector<Object*> result) 
{
    this->result.swap (result);
}
```

Comment: Ah whoops that was a typo in the class definition, I meant to have a reference in the constructor, but regardless you've answered my question, thanks. I was hoping to avoid having the vector first constructed and then copied into `Result`, I was hoping I could have `Result` effectively take ownership of it and extend its lifetime - without copying it.

Comment: @user1520427: you haven't shown the definition of the constructor, only the declaration, so there's no way for us to tell whether it is copied or not, we'll have to take your word for it. However, since the constructor of `Result` takes a non-const reference, `Result(FuncA())` is ill-formed according to the standard. MSVC allows it as an extension. Also, that constructor is private and `FuncB` isn't a friend, so it's ill-formed for a second reason. Unless I've misunderstood, this isn't real code, so you might not get real answers about it.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: is copy elision allowed when copying from a named constructor parameter (i.e. *not* a temporary) to a data member in an initialization list? Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think it is, so I think that `Result(std::vector<Object*> result) : result(result) {}` must copy the vector. In C++11, the obvious thing would be to have an rvalue reference constructor that move-constructs the data member.

Comment: @SteveJessop The code is based on real code, but I cut a bit out to just focus on what the issue was. Anyway, even if I pass the value in by reference, it will then be copied within the function, so there will be at least one copy? If I pass by value, there could be two (one copy into constructor, then one into member variable)? I get a little confused about when to use reference and when not to (and when stuff gets copied for that matter), at the moment I usually always use reference unless it needs to be modified in the function.

Comment: @SteveJessop: here you use `std::move`: `Result(std::vector<Object*> result) : result(std::move(result)) {} ` will perform correctly in every case. The copy elision takes place at the constructor call site.

Comment: @AlexandreC: OK. In C++03 I suppose it would be `Result(std::vector<Object*> r) { result.swap(r); }`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, this is how we used to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the wrong way to go about doing what you want to do. The vector gets destroyed when `Result` goes out of scope. The memory the pointers in the vector point to does not.

So you can return a vector and still use it, but if the pointers in a copy of that vector are freed, you'll run into UB.

Having a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>` instead will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: One of the reasons for using this class is to deal with the memory issues, it will release all pointers when it gets destroyed. But yea, I probably should use using shared_ptrs :/

Comment: @user1520427 exactly. But releasing the pointers when it's destroyed potentially leaves you with copies of those pointers that are now invalid.

Comment: Hmm this is true, although for how I intend to use it in this specific case I don't think I'll run into that issue. But anyway, for most cases should shared ptrs be used? What's a situation where it'd be best not to use them?

Comment: @user1520427 a situation where you shouldn't use `shared_ptr` is when you can use `unique_ptr`. In your case, it seems that ownership is shared, that's why I didn't suggest `unique_ptr` in the first place. But otherwise, you should always prefer them to raw, C-style pointers.